# Intermittent iOS 14 Safari text mangling

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone, safari

does anyone have a clue why I am having issues with iOS sometimes mangling some text on my web page. It seems to happens sometimes then rectifies itself and occurs for some iPhone users but not others.

Here is a screen shot of the mangled text:

[image: Here is a screen shot of the mangled text]

Here is a screen shot of the normal text:

[image: Here is a screen shot of the normal text]

Here is some CSS on the containing HTML div that may shed some light on this?

```
.v-application .font-weight-light {
    font-weight: 300!important;
}
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
*, :after, :before {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
user agent stylesheet
div {
    display: block;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px)
.slide-content.is-even, .slide-content.is-odd {
    text-align: center;
}
.color-1 {
    color: #fff;
}

<style>
.work[data-v-e3c177cc] {
    font-size: clamp(18px,1.6vw,1.6em);
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px)
.contact, .work {
    line-height: 1.3!important;
}
```

Any help appreciated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping I have solved this?

I was rendering some plain text via a JSON string in a Vue.js template using standard `{{ [content] }}` syntax.

I have now switched to using `vhtml="[content]"` instead. It seems to work for me but needs further testing on iOS devices.

Maybe it was a shadow DOM / JSON parsing / rendering delay issue?